# Automatic ESXi backups, is this possible?

Tags: backup, raid, esxi

Since ESXi does not support software RAID, the only option would be to use a hardware RAID controller. However, I would like to avoid buying one for a while, until I finally decide to keep using ESXi for good.

So an alternative to RAID 1 would be, for example, to put all the VMs on one hard drive and have this drive automatically backup (let's say daily) to the second hard drive. Is there any way to make this work in ESXi?

Comment: 1. `Since ESXi does not support software RAID, the only option would be to use a hardware RAID controller` - Yes, that is what people generally do. 2. If you're not even sure that you'll continue to use vSphere then why are you putting important VM's that need to be backed up on it?

Comment: Google for "GhettoVCB"

Comment: @joeqwerty who said that they are important? :) If I buy one hard drive and I find out it's faulty it won't be fun.

Comment: If they're not important then why do you need to back them up? If they're important enough to backup then they're important enough to put on proper hardware. That being said, there are a bazillion backup products for vSphere but none that I know of that will allow you to do scheduled back ups with the free version. Trilead VM Explorer is a fairly good product but you'll have to pay for it to get the scheduled backup feature.

Comment: @joeqwerty ok i will have a look at those, thanks. I want to backup because I **might** keep using esxi, and since I am still not sure, that makes more sense to me than spending £100 on a hardware raid controller

Comment: @EugenRieck that looks interesting. Do you know if it allows me to save the backups on a different hard drive than the one the vms are running on though?

Comment: Yes it does, plus some network destinations - as you might find out by reading the docs ;-)

Comment: @EugenRieck right, I had a quick look, but I am on my phone now, not ideal to read technical docs :D turn the comment into an answer so I can accept it ;)

Comment: @joeqwerty I see your point though. Let's say that it's not too much about the data, as it's about the configuration effort :D

Comment: Understood. Looks like you've got a solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thoroughly recommend [GhettoVCB](https://github.com/lamw/ghettoVCB) as described in [VM Community Forum](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8760). It allows to back up to different datastores and network locations.